# WSO2 API manager migration from 2.0 to 2.5

Tags: api, web-services, wso2, migration, wso2-api-manager

We are trying to migrate the API manager from 2.0 to 2.5.
followed the instructions from the WSO2 Documentation.

After the migration we are have strange issues
1. No download wsdl link for the API's shown in Store (Though publisher shows)
2. Static never expiry tokens are also not visible in store(Though publisher shows)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Removing+Unused+Tokens+from+the+Database#RemovingUnusedTokensfromtheDatabase-ConfiguringAPIManagerfortokencleanup

This documentation fixed the issue.